# What is a list of book that i need to read as a prerequisite before start reading "lectures of logic and set theory vol.1 by George Tourlakas"?

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question, big-list

What is a list of formal textbook that i need to impose myself to read as a prerequisite before start reading a book called lectures of logic and set theory vol.1 by George Tourlakas?

That book is too challenging for me start to read as i didn't take any logic class before.

Preview of the book: http://books.google.com/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PR2&dq=lecture+of+logicand+set+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f6ROVOrPPIa1sQSmo4KwDQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=lecture%20of%20logicand%20set%20theory&f=false

Comment: To get you into the right mindset, may I humbly suggest some educational freeware I have developed. For more info and free, full-function download visit my website at http://www.dcproof.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check out the Teach Yourself Logic guide to the logic literature, downloadable at http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl -- the full PDF version gives extended descriptions about what is covered in what book, and should enable to find what you need depending on your background/mathematical competence.